# MYSQL Error Code: 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

I'm following the instructions in this video to try and build a retrosheet SQL database, and I'm having issues executing the SQL script to do a bulk insert into the database.

I was previously able to do this with MYSQL 5.7, but recently upgrade to 8.0 and I'm now getting stuck at this step. I've tried following the advice in the video to comment out the --secure-file-priv option in the my.ini file, and I've also tried setting it to the directory location of the data I want to import, but in both situations I'm still getting the error message "Error Code: 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement."

I've also run this `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` command in SQLYOG to verify that the secure_file_priv option has been updated.

Has anything changed between mysql versions that this method no long works to turn of the --secure-file-priv option?

Video I'm watching for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9S8bYt9JZY

EDIT:

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| secure_file_priv | NULL |

Full error message:

> Error occured at:2018-01-14 13:47:23 Line no.:1 Error Code: 1290 - The
> MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it
> cannot execute this statement

Comment: *I've tried following the advice in the video to comment out the --secure-file-priv option in the my.ini file* , that's a bad advice in my opinion. Start by posting the load data code, the output of  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` . And please do not post external links

Comment: Never use doubtful videos - read Reference Manual. [`secure_file_priv` system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv). Recommendation - add this option into service starting command line.

Comment: *Has anything changed between mysql versions that this method no long works to turn of the --secure-file-priv option?* #1 - WHAT method? #2 - No, nothing was changed.

Comment: @Akina the method of commenting out the line "secure-file-priv=" from the my.ini file. This had worked for me previously.

The reason I am relying on that video is because the only purpose of me using mysql is to house the data they were referencing. It's as close to a step by step guide for my specific use case as I will ever find.

Comment: @Akina trying to set --secure-file-priv option from command line to an empty string: --secure-file-priv=""; gives the error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--secure-file-priv=""' at line 1

Comment: @ErgestBasha I added an edit

Comment: Show the code you're trying to run, instead of linking us to (what you claim to be) a video. (Honestly, I expect it is, but do YOU follow random links on the Internet, because someone you don't know asked you to?)

Comment: You have tried to execute the command line option as SQL statement? This is obviously wrong.

Comment: Please have this line in your my.ini: `secure-file-priv=""` , because of [If set to NULL, the server disables import and export operations.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv:~:text=If%20set%20to%20NULL%2C%20the%20server%20disables%20import%20and%20export%20operations.), and double quotes in a Windows environment are ....  (evil and confusing), and also hard to explain when you will have "an empty string", or "no value"

Comment: @Luuk I have tried this as well in the my.ini:

secure-file-priv=""

And I'm still getting the error message "Error occured at:2018-01-14 13:47:23
Line no.:1
Error Code: 1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"

Comment: @Luuk I will not suggest setting secure-file-priv to empty [If empty, the variable has no effect. This is not a secure setting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv)

Comment: @ErgestBasha both `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` and `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` show an empty value (this is after I changed the line in the my.ini file to be `secure-file-priv=""` per Luuk suggestion.

Comment: @ErgestBasha windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on MySQL 8.0.29 on Windows 11.

On my.ini be sure to have

```
# Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
```

or another path.

Then create your file and upload it to the above path.

I created the test.txt file with some data and upload in the Uploads folder as below image.

[image]

Then I created a test table.

```
create table test (
id int );
```

Used the load data command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

And everything works fine.

```
select * from test;
```

[image]

Comment: On my test/development system I leave the setting to: `secure-file-priv=""`. This might be insecure, but makes testing easier, because import can be done from ANY directory.